# unity рождает пиксель из неоткуда

Tags: unity3d

после добавления теста на канвас, юнити начал рождать на текстуре лишний пиксель.
[image: Тот самый фантомный пиксель]

на текстуре этого пикселя нет. когда натягиваю текстуру на другой объект этот пиксель всё равно рождается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

причём у меня 3 текстуры для анимации. и пиксель появился на всех

Answer (score 0, accepted):

итак, методом тыка я обнаружил. что если сменить в настройках текстуры Format с Automatic на RGBA 32Bit. то оно работает верно.

[image: что надо прокрутить чтобы работало]